# Second Email is not sending in Devise Invitable for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

Hi I have a batch invitation module where a user can invite multiple users to register

And I am using `devise_invitable` gem

The problem is that, the first inputted email is being sent but for the second one, I am not receiving any email(s).

Here's my form:

```
.user-unit
  %h2 Invite
  = form_tag batch_invite_users_path, :method => :post do
    = label_tag "Emails"
    = text_field_tag :user_email_1
    = text_field_tag :user_email_2
    %br
    = submit_tag "Send", class: 'btn-primary'
```

And my controller:

```
  def batch_invite
    if request.post?
      valid_emails = []
      @invalid_emails = []
      @invited_emails = []
      @invited_emails << params[:user_email_1] << params[:user_email_2]
      @invited_emails.each do |email|
        if email =~ Devise.email_regexp
          user = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
          user.roles << Role.find(3)
          valid_emails << email
        else
          @invalid_emails << email
        end
      end
      if valid_emails.empty?
        flash[:notice] = "No email have been sent."
      else
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = "An invitation has been sent to #{valid_emails.join(',')}."
      end
    end
  end
```

I have to fields, `user_email_1` and `user_email_2` and I converted those into an array so that I could loop it for the `!invite` method provided by the gem

`user_email_1` is receiving an email but not the `user_email_2`

Here's my log/trace: http://pastebin.com/1kqvZXWC

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing really stands out either from your logs or your code. Do you mind putting more log statements in your code? The best place would be to add a log statement at the top of the `each` loop saying "Sending email to #{email}". Also log the valid_emails variable at the end of the method.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Here's the latest trace with logged `valid_email` http://pastebin.com/Ys4UqdUg My assumption is that it has something to do with the invitations_controller? or not? where can I actually override this method `invite!`

Comment: Your log now shows two mails being sent out. See this: `User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'shielajanesalamat@ymail.com' LIMIT 1` and this: `User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'shielas@sourcepad.com' LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Yah it just says being sent but actually the second email is not receiving an email yet :(

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder? ymail.com has a much stricter spam filter than sourcepad.com. It probably uses DKIM to protect its users. For testing our application, use email addresses on [mailinator.com](http://mailinator.com/). They have throwaway inboxes which expire in 15minutes which is enough time for you to test and verify.